# Line of code too long for python to interpret?

Tags: python

So I'm doing some work with win32com.client module. I did some webscraping to make dataframes of all of the massive amount of enumerations. The webscraping was successful but one module will not load unless I comment out the line.

I've made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Melendowski/d0b9779d54556f73bceb97de68634074) of the code because a few the lines are almost 13k characters long.

The error when I try `import office_reverse_enumerations.py` is

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

On line 17. If I comment out line 17 it runs just fine.

I programmatically generated that line, well, all the lines.

An example write is

```
enum_file.write(f"{enum_names[idx][df_idx]}_reverse = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({df_r_enum.to_dict()})\n")
```

```
>>> import office_reverse_enumerations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\sdfg-Mobile\Documents\Gits\power_point_generator\office_reverse_enumerations.py", line 17

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Melendowski/56f213859844e412ea82b0d736cd8062) is the code that I used to generate the file.

Comment: Have you tried just `import office_reverse_enumerations`? I can't reproduce this locally, even using the file you provided.

Comment: That's exactly what I do and I get the error posted in the OP edit.

Comment: Huh, what version of python are you using?

Comment: The error says "in position 0", so I doubt it is to do with the line length.

Comment: Python 3.7.1 Anaconda

Comment: A general concept of good practice is to devide data and code, an other would be to use line breaks where it increases readability.

Comment: @KlausD. I understand, but like I said in OP, this file was programmatically generated and it should just work because I'm constructing it with python using fstrings, and a `pd.df.to_dict()`.

Comment: Have you set an encoding for "enum_file" when writing?

Comment: Negative. I use the default `with open(f'{product}_enumerations.py','w+') as enum_file:`

Comment: Then try to add encoding="utf-8" to this.

Comment: @MichaelButscher That did it. If you make an answer post I will select it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `open` to write a text file without specifying the `encoding`, a system-dependent default encoding is used (which can be retrieved with `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`).

Python code files are expected to be UTF-8-encoded so the solution is to explicitly specify `encoding="utf-8"` in the `open` function when writing the code file.

Answer (score 1):

Your text has this inside:

```
>>> text[16700:16900]
"ith no border and callout line segments forming a U-shape', 183: 'Line inverse', 166: 'Division symbol  \xc3\x83\xc2\xb7', 167: 'Equivalence symbol  =', 164: 'Subtraction symbol  -', 165: 'Multiplication symbol  "
```

I hope once you know the position and contents, you will be able to fix this =)

ps. The suspicious part is: `166: 'Division symbol  \xc3\x83\xc2\xb7'`